# Having problems with OpenLayers in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, location

I had some issues with a site I'm building so I decided to start over with a fresh Drupal install... but when I install/enable OpenLayers I get this ugliness http://pastebin.com/XJYy76n1

I have absolutely no idea what can this be and it's been driving me a little crazy for the past couple of days.

Any ideas?

Edit: for some additional incomprehensible info, I just enabled the test suite and ran it against the openlayers module and got the following: http://pastebin.com/MHdtHxNm

Comment: Please title your issue better. The test suite is seemingly completely broken. The error you are getting should be "impossible", to get in a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you are seeing, are mostly harmless. PHP on your server is configured to be very strict, which is a good thing, and the Openlayers have previously not been very strict about the coding standards.

I haven't looked specifically at the errors you are seeing, but when I've seen similar issues, I've almost always found the problem fixed in the dev version.

As no-one is actively maintaining the module, there is not likely going to be  a new release any time soon. You're best option is probably to try dev, and report the issue if that doesn't help.

The ugly workaround is to turn down strictness on the error reporting on your php install.

You can also give the less feature rich but newer [Leaflet](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet) module a try.

Comment: thanks for that... that makes sense. I'm trying to get this up quick so I used MAMP instead of keep trying in the VM... different php.ini, different php version...